# Install octave 3.8.0 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, compiling, octave

With the following commands

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf octave-3.8.0.tar.bz2
cd octave-3.8.0
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I have errors in the make and make install phases and octave does not install.
Do you have any suggestion? Thanks for any help

Here are the error messages at the end of the make and make install commands:

```
/usr/local/include/llvm/PassManager.h:34:15: error: 'PassManager' is already declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/llvm/PassManager.h:35:15: error: 'FunctionPassManager' is already declared in this scope
corefcn/pt-jit.cc: In member function 'bool tree_jit::initialize()':
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1891:48: error: cannot convert 'llvm::legacy::PassManager*' to 'llvm::PassManager*' in assignment
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1892:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::PassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:46:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::PassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1894:55: error: cannot convert 'llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManager*' to 'llvm::FunctionPassManager*' in assignment
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1896:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1900:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1901:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1902:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1903:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1904:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1905:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1906:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:1907:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc: In member function 'void tree_jit::optimize(llvm::Function*)':
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:2003:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::PassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:46:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::PassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:2004:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/jit-util.h:45:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct llvm::FunctionPassManager'
corefcn/pt-jit.cc:2010:34: error: 'F_Binary' is not a member of 'llvm::raw_fd_ostream'
make[3]: *** [corefcn/corefcn_libcorefcn_la-pt-jit.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with building octave 3.8.0 against LLVM >= 3.4.  There is updated information in this bug report:
https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?41061

Answer (score 1):

i installed the 3.8 octave version following this instruction - works great. there is a quite long list of dependencies packages which is also instilled if you follow the instructions.

http://blogs.bu.edu/mhirsch/2013/12/compiling-octave-3-8/

cheers
seeb

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you didn't install important libraries along with Octave as I glanced the error message. My suggestion goes with Installing **Octave** properly from **ubuntu software center**, then it will automatically detect which library is missing from your system, thus adding it and installing it along with **Octave**. If you don't know how to install from **ubuntu software center** just tell me , I can instruct you step by step. 
Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately Ubuntu software center installs octave version 3.2.4 while I would install the last version: octave version 3.8.0. I see that the problem should be LLVM  libray (which I installed) but I don't know how to proceed. Thank you again for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

llvm is used by the optional jit. The jit makes octave perform better but it is not strictly necessary. To prevent the octave build from looking for llvm, use the `--disable-jit` flag like so:

```
./configure --disable-jit
make
sudo make install
```